# Mean stack deployed successfully on heroku but I get Application Error

Tags: mongodb, heroku, web-deployment, mean-stack, mean

I successfully deployed my app to Heroku, Added mLab as my add-on
I also set

heroku config:set MONGOLAB_URI=mongodb://[myusername]:[mypassword]@ds119508.mlab.com:19508/heroku_l1q51vhd

but still I get:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Any number of things could be wrong. Please post the output from `https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<app-name>/logs`

Comment: Thanks Harald for the response, I added the log into the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. The problem was with authentication. I made new user/pass and it works. You can use Mongochef to check if your connection and authentication with db is correct.